Excel - Formula to extract total time above a specific temperature
I have 100 files, each about 30K lines of data like this:

As shown, the instances are not sequential. I wonder if I can write a formula capable of looking at all instances >0°F, then look at the date/time and add the total time in hrs. It was above that temperature.
I've tried index/match, xlookup, but nothing more streamlined to my problem. What I've tried required a lot of formulas but only adding them manually by segment, not a formula capable of adding a total of n segments.
For this example, the result is 4.1 hours, which was calculated adding the total for each segment found (2) the first is 2.3 hrs (from 9:26:14 - 11:41:14) the second is 1.8 hrs (from 12:01:14 - 13:51:14).

Look into SUMIF

Thanks for the feedback, always appreciated.

I think there is an issue here of whether to include the difference between the last positive and the first negative. The answers seem to include it as far as I can see. What happens if there is an isolated positive value?

I would like to know how the different options below perform with your large data set(s). Power Query would be a good option for processing multiple files - please let me know if you're interested.

Option with REDUCE:
=LET(
    input, B2:D30000,
    dtime, LAMBDA(i, INDEX(input, i, 1) + INDEX(input, i, 2)),
    val, LAMBDA(i, INDEX(input, i, 3)),
    total_intervals, REDUCE(
        0,
        SEQUENCE(ROWS(input)),
        LAMBDA(acc, cur,
            acc +
                IF(
                    OR(cur = 1, val(cur) <= 0, val(cur - 1) <= 0),
                    0,
                    dtime(cur) - dtime(cur - 1)
                )
        )
    ),
    VSTACK(
        "Total time for all instances > 0°F",
        TEXT(total_intervals, "[h]""h"" mm""m""")
    )
)


With Named Function

To make it easier to apply the formula with multiple inputs, we could define a named function with:
=LAMBDA(input, LET(dtime, LAMBDA(i, INDEX(input, i, 1) + INDEX(input, i, 2)), 
val, LAMBDA(i, INDEX(input, i, 3)), 
REDUCE(0, SEQUENCE(ROWS(input)), LAMBDA(acc,cur, acc 
+ IF(OR(cur = 1, val(cur) <= 0, val(cur - 1) <= 0), 0, dtime(cur) - dtime(cur - 1)))) * 24))

then apply with different ranges
=totalHoursForAboveZero('path[filname]sheet'!range)

or 

=totalHoursForAboveZero(B2:D30000)



Adding formula via VBA

Break into parts with length < 255
Prepare double quotes

Just a quick suggestion to set the formula only - you can fit it into another routine for adding into multiple files.
Sub InsertTotalTimeFormula()

    part1 = "=LAMBDA(input, LET(dtime, LAMBDA(i, INDEX(input, i, 1) + INDEX(input, i, 2)), val, LAMBDA(i, INDEX(input, i, 3)), total_intervals, REDUCE(0, SEQUENCE(ROWS(input)), "
    part2 = "LAMBDA(acc,cur, acc + IF(OR(cur = 1, val(cur) <= 0, val(cur - 1) <= 0), 0, dtime(cur) - dtime(cur - 1)))), VSTACK(""Total time for all instances > 0°F"", TEXT(total_intervals,  ""[h]\h mm\m""))))"
    inputRange = "(B2:D30000)"
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Range("H4").Select
        Selection.Formula2 = part1 & part2 & inputRange
        Selection.Columns.AutoFit 
    End With

End Sub


I'm impressed man, and I appreciate the help. I've never seen a formula like this.

I hope it works with your data with large numbers of rows :)

I need you help one last time my friend, how can I write your formula in VBA to inject it on multiple files. I have the code to run it on multiple files but I'm having problems with how is written in VBA.

So I set it up to just open each file in a specific folder, (just because we're getting more and more every day) and the goal is to copy your formula in a specific cell for all files, and I wrote another macro to extract the value from the cell from each file.
I already have the macros to do this on all files and to extract the data, all I'm missing is how to write your formula is the code to run it. Thanks!

@skywolf90, I've added a suggestion - please check.

It worked wonderfully my friend! Thank you very much for taking the time and effort to help me I appreciate it a lot.

When I first tested it, it worked, but now is only computing and writing the value of the result instead of the formula.

Please make sure in your macro you're setting the formula Selection.Formula2 and not Selection.Value. I have tested it again with different inputs such at H4, L10 etc. and each time the formula is written and not the value. If you want, I could take a look the the code that's giving the value instead of formula.

I believe you need to check that both the current and the next row are both greater than zero in order to come up with the same answer that you show.
Your answer and explanation of how you derived it shows that you are NOT counting the difference between a last positive and a following negative.
Accordingly, try:
not taking date into account:
=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D21>0)*(D3:D22>0)*(C3:C22-C2:C21))*24
taking date into account:
=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D21>0)*(D3:D22>0)*((B3:B22+C3:C22)-(B2:B21+C2:C21)))*24
Format result as Number with 1 decimal place to reproduce your result


4 hours 5 minutes does agree with OP's answer as I understand it. If I were doing this for real I would be tempted to try some sort of interpolation because it seems that this (though correct) might be an underestimate, but all we can do is answer the question!

@TomSharpe Concur. And I think there are too many unknowns to make a determination as to the type of interpolation that might improve accuracy, if any.

I appreciate the input, however running either formula returned #VALUE!

@skywolf90 You can see from the screenshot that it works here. There must be something about your data or the way you adapted the formula to it that is causing that error.

Create a new column with the formula in the range F2:F21:
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),0,(B3+C3)-(B2+C2))

Then you can generate the total using the formula:
=SUMIF(D2:D21,">0",F2:F21)*24

Which gives the output:

If you want a single formula that takes into account changes in date then:
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:B21+C3:C21)-(B2:B20+C2:C20),D2:D20>0)*24


Thanks a lot! It makes a lot of sense now. If I run the global formula it returns #VALUE!

One simple solution is like this:
In a new column with IF calculate the time difference between two values if it is above 0:
=IF(D3>0,C3-C2,0)

Then simply Sum that column to get the result:

An even better way is to use SUMPRODUCT function without the need to use a new column:
=SUMPRODUCT((D3:D7>0)*(C3:C7-C2:C6))

Result:


Pretty useful, thanks for the recommendation. I'll give this a try.

The second formula of yours, returns #VALUE! when I run it at full scale (30,000 rows of data and different dates and times)
